# Application windows in DarkMode are dark red at the bottom of the screen

Tags: macos

I have this very odd problem and can only replicate it on 1 MacbookPro.

When I drag a window to the bottom of the screen in Dark Mode, it changes to a dark red / maroon.

When I drag that same window to the top of the screen, the colour gradually changes back to the original Dark Mode grey.

---

### Screenshots

**Red Image** — https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOgtV.jpg

**Grey Image** — https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeeEE.jpg

---

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: In Dark Mode, by design, windows pick up color from your Desktop picture. What does that look like?

Comment: @ken no, it picks up colours from windows underneath the Dark Mode window. In this instance, it was onto pot a plain white web page.

Comment: No, it's the desktop picture even if there's another window.

Comment: @ken no it’s not. On my other MacBook Pro, I have the exact same wallpaper but don’t have this problem.